# Java login verification does not work?

Tags: java, authentication, java.util.scanner

I've declared all of the relevant string variables in my code. My issue is my login verification. I am trying to verify if a string exists within my text file when a button is clicked. The layout of which is "username: john25, password: john25". Can anyone show me exactly where I'm going wrong

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:]
    if(evt.getSource()==jButton1){
        boolean found = false;
        username = ("");
        password = ("");
        filepath =("doctorFiles.txt");

        username = jTextField1.getText();
        password = jPasswordField1.getText();

        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

            while(x.hasNext() && !found ) {
                username = x.next();
                password = x.next();

                if(username.trim().equals(username.trim()) && password.trim().equals(password.trim()))
                {
                    found = true;
                   if(found==true){
                     welcomePage goback = new welcomePage();
                     goback.setVisible(true);
                     dispose(); 
                     }
                }
                x.close();
                System.out.println(found);

            }


        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error is "+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To improve the question, add some description of what you expect to happen vs. what is actually happening. Also include any error messages that appear. In general, you can use a debugger, or System.out.println() statements to inspect the state of your application at every line of code. See here: https://youtu.be/i_Gonsk_qGA

Answer (score 0):

Why are you stepping your own variables in here:

```
username = jTextField1.getText();
password = jPasswordField1.getText();


username = x.next();
password = x.next();
```

This doesn't have any sense and in your if

```
 if(username.trim().equals(username.trim()) && password.trim().equals(password.trim()))
```

You are comparing your same variable and it will be always true. 
Try to create new variables

```
String usernameFromTxt = x.next();
String passwordFromTxt = x.next();

if(usernameFromTxt .trim().equals(username.trim()) && usernameFromTxt .trim().equals(password.trim()))
```